# ESP32-C3 ESP-IDF esp logging no output in serial monitor

Tags: esp-idf

i'm new to programming with esp-idf and I'm having a problem with getting some output while debugging my esp32-c3. Following [this](https://esp32tutorials.com/getting-started-tutorial-esp32-esp-idf/) tutorial.

Clearly it's a simple mistake but i can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "esp_log.h"

void app_main(void)
{
    ESP_LOGW("LOG", "This is a warning");
    ESP_LOGI("LOG", "This is an info");
    ESP_LOGD("LOG", "This is a debug");
    ESP_LOGV("LOG", "This is a verbose");
}
```

via Menuconfig i set

> Component config -> Log output -> default verbosity -> Verbose

I'm using PlatformIO in VS Code so my platformio.ini looks like that:

```
[env:dfrobot_beetle_esp32c3]
platform = espressif32 
board = dfrobot_beetle_esp32c3
framework = espidf
monitor_speed = 115200
monitor_dtr = 0
monitor_rts = 0
```

everything compiles without a problem. I'm using the "upload and monitor" button in the PlattformIO tab but after upload my console output stays empty:

```
--- forcing RTS inactive
--- Terminal on COM6 | 115200 8-N-1
--- Available filters and text transformations: colorize, debug, default, direct, esp32_exception_decoder, hexlify, log2file, nocontrol, printable, send_on_enter, time
--- Quit: Ctrl+C | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Turns out this seems to be a kind a of bug in the serial terminal.

Solution:

Even though i forced the DTR to be off via the setting in the platformio.ini, i toggled the DTR setting on and off again while the serial terminal is open via

> CTRL + T & CTRL + D

(2x) and then the output of the ESP is getting printed.